# How to avoid dark/black area in blender when using hemi?

Tags: blender, light

I use blender to render patent images, which require "black and white" drawings. Hemi is very handy because 1 hemi lamp is enough and no shadows. But this time I got this:

[image]

After using gimp Edge detect -> Revert colors -> Auto-crop image -> Threshold to 239 -> 1 bit color index, I got this:
[image]

It's still usable, but it's ugly! So what happened? Hemi lamp used to be simple and works great! All I need is to put 1 single hemi lamp at origin (0,0,0)!

Comment: You might have better luck asking this on the [Blender SE](http://blender.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thanks a lot, bro!